# unable to view docker images on google kubernetes node v1.21.4-gke.2300

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a new kubernetes cluster (GKE) and installed an application using helm.

I was able to locate the gke-node on which my pod was deployed using the command,
`kubectl get pod -n namespace -o wide`

Post that i logged on to the kubernetes-node, however on this node i am unable to view the docker images. This is the case on v1.21.4-gke.2300

In the older-version v1.19.13-gke.1200, i was able to observe the docker-images on nodes when they were pulled from repository

I can view the list of docker-images on v1.21.4-gke.2300 with the command
`kubectl get pods -n geo-test -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |  sort |  uniq -c`

But i would like to know where in the cluster are these images getting stored and why i am not able to observe them in the node like i did in the older version

My reason for asking is, because in version v1.19.13-gke.1200, i was able to perform minor changes in the docker-image, build a custom-image and use that for installation instead of storing the images in the gcr and pulling it from there
Any suggestion on how to go about it in the new

[image: v1.19.13-gke.1200]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with GKE node version 1.19, the default node image for Linux nodes is the Container-Optimized OS with containerd (cos_containerd) variant instead of the Container-Optimized OS with Docker (cos) variant.

Now instead of `docker` commands you can use `crictl`. Refer to the [crictl user guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/) for the complete set of supported features and usage information.

Specifically, you can run `crictl images` to list the images, available on the node.

Comment: thanks a ton, i was able to view the images using the crictl
Now will have to check for the command to build the image using crictl,

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the information already given to you, here is a set of commands using crictl. Here you can see the images command, which is to list the images in your container.

```
crictl  [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]
```

COMMANDS:

`attach`: Attach to a running container

`create`: Create a new container

`exec`: Run a command in a running container

`version`: Display runtime version information

`images, image, img`: List images

`inspect`: Display the status of one or more containers

`inspecti`: Return the status of one or more images

`imagefsinfo`: Return image filesystem info

`inspectp`: Display the status of one or more pods

`logs`: Fetch the logs of a container

`port-forward`: Forward local port to a pod

`ps`: List containers

`pull`: Pull an image from a registry

`run`: Run a new container inside a sandbox

`runp`: Run a new pod

`rm`: Remove one or more containers

`rmi`: Remove one or more images

`rmp`: Remove one or more pods

`pods`: List pods

`start`: Start one or more created containers

`info`: Display information of the container runtime

`stop`: Stop one or more running containers

`stopp`: Stop one or more running pods

`update`: Update one or more running containers

`config`: Get and set crictl client configuration options

`stats`: List container(s) resource usage statistics

`completion`: Output bash shell completion code

`help, h`: Shows a list of commands or help for one command

Here is a link to the complete [command list](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md)